# Do I need a CASE expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have the following query which returns an organizations prior year (from the current year, so 2018) total wages.

```
SELECT 
    organization_id, 
    CASE 
       WHEN organization_id IN (SELECT text_1 
                                FROM combo_table_detail 
                                WHERE combo_table_id = 'wageAdjustment') 
          THEN SUM(ISNULL(component_value, 0)) + ISNULL(ctd.number_2, 0) 
          ELSE SUM(ISNULL(component_value, 0)) 
    END AS "total_annual_wage", 
    MAX((begin_date)) AS "total_annual_wage_eff_date" 
FROM   
    actual_pay_hours aph 
LEFT JOIN 
    combo_table_detail ctd ON aph.organization_id = ctd.text_1 
                           AND combo_table_id = 'wageAdjustment' 
WHERE  
    organization_id = 'Org1' 
    AND component_name IN ('earnDef', 'earnings') 
    AND begin_date >= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) 
    AND begin_date < DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
GROUP BY 
    organization_id, ctd.number_2
```

However, I've run across an issue where some organizations either don't have a prior year (some only have 2019 wages), or their latest wages are from 2014. In both cases, the query returns blank values. This is due to the line

```
AND begin_date >= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) 
AND begin_date < DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

The expected result should look something like this:

```
+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------------+
| organization_id | total_annual_wage | total_annual_wage_eff_date |
+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------------+
| Org1            |             50000 | 12/1/2018                  |
+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------------+
```

But instead, it looks like this:

```
+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------------+
| organization_id | total_annual_wage | total_annual_wage_eff_date |
+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------------+
```

This issue seems to be the fact that in the aph table, some units have wages for the 2018 year, while others don't. Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    YEAR(BEGIN_DATE) AS [Begin Date for Org1]
FROM    
    ACTUAL_PAY_HOURS aph
WHERE
    ORGANIZATION_ID = 'Org1'
```

Results:

```
+---------------------+
| Begin Date for Org1 |
+---------------------+
|                1988 |
|                1989 |
|                1990 |
|                1991 |
|                1992 |
|                1993 |
|                1994 |
|                2004 |
|                2005 |
|                2006 |
|                2007 |
|                2008 |
|                2009 |
|                2010 |
|                2011 |
|                2012 |
|                2013 |
|                2014 |
+---------------------+
```

Additionally, the total wages for the prior year are then being adjusted by a value in the CTD (combo_table_detail) table. The issue is that when there are no values for an exisitng year, nothing is returned. What I need is for the wage total to then be 0 - since there isn't any data for that year, but then the value from the CTD table is added.

So, if Org1 has no wages for 2018, it should come out like this:

```
+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+-------+
| organization_id | total_wages | combo_table_value | total |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+-------+
| Org1            |           0 |             25000 | 25000 |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------------+-------+
```

So my question is, what logic can I add to this query that will return a result when the Organization doesn't have any prior year wages, but will still be added to the CTD table resulting in a value being returned?

Comment: Using `Year(begin_date) = Year(Dateadd(year, -1, Getdate()))` in the first place is a bad idea; it's not SARGable. Use proper date logic: `AND BeginDate >= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE())-1,0) AND BeginDate < DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()),0)`. As for your question, not sure what you mean. SQL Server doesn't have `Case` statements, only `CASE` expressions, and using those in the `WHERE` is a bad idea too (as they effect SARGability). NOt sure what you mean by "blank value" either, I assume you mean `NULL`, but that can't be the case here, as you're filtering the data.

Comment: Thanks, I've not heard of this 'SARGable' before, but it makes total sense. As for the Case expression, that's what I meant - not statement. And same goes for blank value - it just doesn't return anything. Do you have a suggestion on to write this query with added logic to account for the date issue?

Comment: "SARGable" means the Search ARGument(ability) of a query. A Query that isn't SARGable means that indexes can't be used to aid the Data Engine to Seek for rows; resulting in index or table scans; which are *often* slower.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on to write this query with added logic to account for the date issue?

Comment: I don't understand the problem I'm afraid, what you describe doesn't make sense. Sample data and expected results would make this easier.

Comment: @Larnu, does my updated question make better sense now?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 2 of the fields in the WHERE clause belong to the joined table.
Try with moving those criteria to the LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT aph.organization_id, 
   ISNULL(SUM(ctd.component_value),0) +
   (CASE 
    WHEN SUM(ctd.component_value) IS NULL
    THEN SUM (
       SELECT d.component_value
       FROM combo_table_detail d
       WHERE d.combo_table_id = 'wageAdjustment'
       AND d.text_1 = aph.organization_id
   )
   ELSE 0
   END) AS [total_annual_wage], 
  MAX(aph.begin_date) AS [total_annual_wage_eff_date]
FROM actual_pay_hours AS aph 
LEFT JOIN combo_table_detail AS ctd 
  ON ctd.text_1 = aph.organization_id
 AND ctd.combo_table_id = 'wageAdjustment' 
 AND aph.component_name IN ('earnDef', 'earnings')
 AND aph.begin_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,1,1)
 AND aph.begin_date < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),1,1)
WHERE aph.organization_id = 'orgID' 
GROUP BY aph.organization_id, ctd.number_2
```

Comment: This looks good, except component_name and begin_date are from the aph table. The only values coming from the ctd table are the combo_table_id, text_1 and number_2.

Comment: Could you explain the logic for?:                                                                             
 `AND ctd.begin_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1, 1, 1)
 AND ctd.begin_date < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1)`

Comment: Seeing is believing.  Just run `select DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1, 1, 1), DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1))` and think about what the logic does with that. Btw, is that CASE really needed?  From the join  it would already know that there's a 'wageAdjustment'?

Comment: Your answer was correct, but I forgot to leave out some important details. I've made some edits to my question to give more information

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    aph.organization_id,
    MAX(aph.begin_date) AS total_annual_wage_eff_date, 
    --earn components sum
    ISNULL( SUM(aph.component_value), 0)
    +
    --adjustment sum, if any
    (
    SELECT ISNULL(SUM(ctd.number_2), 0) 
    FROM combo_table_detail ctd 
    WHERE ctd.text_1 = aph.organization_id
      AND ctd.combo_table_id = 'wageAdjustment'
    ) AS total_annual_wage
FROM actual_pay_hours AS aph
WHERE aph.component_name IN ( 'earnDef', 'earnings' ) 
AND aph.begin_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1, 1, 1)
AND aph.begin_date < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1)
GROUP BY aph.organization_id
```